# Case-sensitivity in QTP 11 question: different results with different cases in VBScipt

Tags: vbscript, qtp, case-sensitive

I found strange behavior in QTP 11 today: expression

```
Browser().Page().WebElement("PositionManagerContainer").WebElement("LoadingMessage").Object.ParentNode.ParentNode
```

Gives error: Object Required ".Object.ParentNode"

But expression

```
Browser().Page().WebElement("PositionManagerContainer").WebElement("LoadingMessage").Object.parentNode.ParentNode
```

(the difference in case of ParentNode member of .Object)
Is correct and works fine without any errors.

Browser is Firefox. In IE it worked fine.

Can someone explain why it happens? Just for interest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a very good (and subtle) point.
In general `.Object` allows access to the native object in the application being tested. Since QTP is VBScript based this means that the `.Object` property of test objects is [`IDispatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318520.aspx).

When working with IE QTP can pass the [MSHTML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741317.aspx) object that IE exposes (and which supports `IDispatch`), since MSHTML is designed to work with VBScript these objects are case insensitive.  However when working with Firefox there is no `IDispatch` supporting object which is exposed by the browser. Therefore QTP has to create a proxy object that implements `IDispatch` by querying the object exposed by Firefox. Since Firefox is designed to work with JavaScript (which **is** case sensitive) this proxy object is automatically case sensitive.

The error you saw came from the fact that the first `ParentNode` returned `Empty` so the second `.ParentNode` threw an error.

Therefore when using `.Object` with Firefox you *must* use the correct casing for the properties and methods you access.